# How to use vnode in vue template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to call the dialog like this:

```js
import demo from './demo.vue';

methods: {
    open() {
      const dialog = this.$dialog({
        content: demo
      });
    }
  }
```

`dialog.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import QfDialog from './qf-dialog';

import ElementQfUI from 'element-qf-ui';
Vue.use(ElementQfUI);

let DialogConstructor = Vue.extend(QfDialog);

export const dialog = (params) => {

  const instance = new DialogConstructor({
    propsData: {
      visible: true,
      ...params
    }
  });

  instance.$mount();

  document.body.appendChild(instance.$el);

  return instance;
}

Vue.prototype.$dialog = dialog;
```

I tried to generate a VNode from a vue object to use in the template, but it gives me following error:

> Error in render: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
> --- property '_renderProxy' closes the circle"

```js
<template>
  <el-dialog :visible.sync="visible" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
    {{ contentTpl }}
  </el-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'qf-dialog',

  props: {
    visible: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      contentTpl: null
    };
  },

  created() {
    // this.content is a vue obj
    let content = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.content));
    let vnode = this.$createElement('demo-cc', content);
    this.contentTpl = [vnode];
  }
};
</script>
```

How do I make `{{contentTpl}}` work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a whole Vue component into your Dialog - not a VNodes

Just use [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

```js
<template>
  <el-dialog :visible.sync="visible" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
    <component :is="content" />
  </el-dialog>
</template>
```

Note that using `:visible.sync` is problematic as Vue does not allow to modify props the component receives